# Localhost not found error appears when trying to go to a different page - ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently working on a basic To Do List on ASP.NET CORE. I have a button on top of the To-Do list to says `"Add Task"` upon clicking on the button you'll be re-directed to a Create Task Form. At the moment when click on the `Add Task` button to be re-directed to the form I am getting a localhost not found error. The URL is correct as it says `http://localhost:51797/Todo/Create` but my `.cshtml` page does not appear. I'm new to ASP.Net so apologies if the reason is obvious but I have gone through my code and I cant seem to find why this is happening.

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Create")]
        public ActionResult Create(int? id, string newText)
        {
            int i = id ?? 0;
            TodoListItem toDo = _todoListService.GetList(i);

            toDo.Text = newText;    //Set new text


            _todoListService.WriteToFile(toDo);


            return RedirectToAction("Index");       
        }

    }
```

This is my `Create.cshtml` page

```
@model TodoListItem
@{

    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h2>Add Task</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Text" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Text" class="form-control" name="newText" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Text" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "create",
                    template: "{controller=Todo}/{action=Create}");

            });
```

Comment: Do you have a HttpGet method that returns the Create page?

Comment: I currently do not, which i'm assuming is the problem? I'll create one rn

Comment: Then that's your problem right there. You're performing a GET request, so you need to have a method that handles that. You decorated the Create with POST, ruling out any GET. Create a second `Create` method, without parameters and return View("Create").

Comment: You post action should have `TodoListItem` model not the `id` and `newText`.Something like `public ActionResult Create(TodoListItem model)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an HTTPGET attribute for the GET action, which should return the create view with an empty model.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new TodoListItem());
}
```

So when you click on Add Task, it will execute this action method and returns the create view.